# Selectable padding between spans while text selecting

Tags: html, css

How make the padding between `span`s selectable while I select a text?

```css
.pad-r {
  padding-right:5px;
}
span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="pad-r">123</span><span class="pad-r">456</span><span>789</span>
```

---

The example of the problem:

[image]

The expected result:

[image]

The selected text should not contain space characters, only these numbers.

I want to display long numbers in formatted way. Selecting of them (in order to copy) should not be spitted to parts (it's the problem). And the value that user receives to the clipboard* should have no spaces, only numbers.

**Via Ctrl+C or the context menu (not programmatically).*

Comment: what exactly is the problem? You want distance between numbers but no space?  Look into string theory perhaps you can find the right dimension

Comment: Yeah @KeyKi I mean your expected result is to select spaces so no way around that I think. You can't select padding, you're selecting text node content.

So it seems like you're trying to get the visual result of selecting spaces, but you don't want them in the value of the selection like when copy/pasting. You should probably rephrase your question to clarify. If this is the case you're probably best off having spaces and allowing selection - but stripping the space characters out of the value as needed for copy/paste, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letter-spacing` CSS property do the work.

The only thing I had to change the HTML markup in additional.

*(Note: I have specially written HTML in one line, it's important thing.)*

```css
.r {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span>12</span><span class="r">3</span><span>45</span><span class="r">6</span><span>789</span>
```

Comment: Nice thing (in my case) that `letter-spacing` adds the extra space only to the right, not to both sides.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using paddings instead of regular spaces?

css

```
span {
      font-size: 20px
    }
```

html

```
 <span>123 456 789</span>
```